# Polygon covering one twice the size with seven copies

Tags: geometry

Let P be a convex polygon in the plane, and let P’ be an enlarged version of P, dilated by a scale factor of 2. Show that seven copies of P can completely cover P’.

I vaguely remember seeing this problem online, but I can’t find the source.

I noticed that seven circles of radius 1 can cover a circle of radius 2. Their intersections also trace a regular hexagon. Is that useful? I couldn’t make much progress.

Comment: Some context to add to question : $\mathbb R^2$ is a [Doubling space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space) with constant $7$ as mentioned in the post (Kindly add to your post). In any case, you can perhaps try to look for a bijection from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself such that the unit circle centred at the origin maps to a copy of $P$ with $0$ in its interior. Doing this, you can probably map the entire ball covering picture into a polygon covering picture.

Comment: A solution to this problem can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/Let-P-be-a-convex-polygon-in-the-plane-and-let-P-be-an-enlarged-version-of-P-dilated-by-a-scale-factor-of-2-How-can-you-show-that-seven-copies-of-P-can-completely-cover-P)

Comment: @AnayGautam There is no solution on that page.